# Creating an incremental model in DBT+Spark with no unique_key

Tags: databricks, dbt

I have a user table as follows

```
|------------|-----------------|
|  user_id   |   visited       |
|------------|-----------------|
|    1       |   12-23-2021    |
|    1       |   11-23-2021    |
|    1       |   10-23-2021    |
|    2       |   01-21-2021    |
|    3       |   02-19-2021    |
|    3       |   02-25-2021    |
|------------|-----------------|
```

I'm trying to create an incremental model to get the user's recent visited date.

Since the incremental model needs an unique key, I'm concatenating user_id||visited -> unique_id

**DBT + Spark**

```
{{ config(
    materialized='incremental',
    file_format='delta',
    unique_key='unique_id',
    incremental_strategy='merge'
) }}

with CTE as (
  select user_id,
         visited,
     user_id||visited as unique_id
  from my_table
 
   {% if is_incremental() %}
    where visited >= date_add(current_date, -1)
   {% endif %}
)

select user_id,
       unique_id,
       max(visited) as recent_visited_date
from CTE
group by 1,2
```

This above model is giving me the result as follows

```
|------------|------------------|-----------------------|
|  user_id   |   unique_id      |recent_visited_date    |
|------------|------------------|-----------------------|
|    1       |   112-23-2021    |       12-23-2021      |
|    1       |   111-23-2021    |       11-23-2021      |
|    1       |   110-23-2021    |       10-23-2021      |
|    2       |   201-21-2021    |       01-21-2021      |
|    3       |   302-19-2021    |       02-19-2021      |
|    3       |   302-25-2021    |       02-25-2021      |
|------------|------------------|-----------------------|
```

The output what I wanted is

```
|------------|------------------------|
|  user_id   | recent_visited_date    |
|------------|------------------------|
|    1       |     12-23-2021         |
|    2       |     01-21-2021         |
|    3       |     02-25-2021         |
|------------|------------------------|
```

I know that for the incremental model with **merge** strategy, the **unique_id** should be in the final table in order to compare
but having the unique_id is giving the wrong output

Is there any other way around to get the max(visited) for the user?

Comment: `user_id` is enough for your `unique key`

Comment: @DatNguyen But the user_id is not unique in the source table

Comment: the `unique key` config - it is for your destination table, not source one